# Should I do documents transformation at once or a pair at a time for auto grading with cosine similarity?

Tags: svd, cosine-similarity, tf-idf, latent-semantic-analysis

I'm developing auto grading essay that compares the similarity between the answer key and student answer with cosine similarity. This one is written in php. Let's say in a course there are 30 - 100 students. So my documents should be 31 - 101. For simplicity, take 31.

Should I perform TF-IDF on all documents at once and then do the auto grade for each answer with cossim, or should I perform a pair at a time (one student answer and answer key)? The current approach in my code is a pair at once

Another related document transformation is LSA. I'm thinking about applying LSA on the auto grading method. If I'm gonna do LSA, it should be all documents at once, right?. But, the question is, is 31 documents enough to perform LSA? I think it can be less than 31 considering certain circumstances (like some students didn't take a quiz on time). At this point, is LSA a viable approach?

Another question, how many dimensions should I preserve then when computing truncated svd? I read some articles that use the low-rank approximation for preserving the most important topics. What do you think?

I'm actually already done writing the svd part. I'm taking it from JAMA, and get the low-rank approximation from this [code](https://github.com/vladkolodka/SVD/blob/master/svd.php) on line 412 - 419.

Sorry for my bad english. I'm also new in machine learning.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site, newtocoding. For the sake of my poor heart, can you please confirm that this is not a class with actual, real students in it?

Comment: @JohnMadden It is real students